# Laravel- How to stay on same page after logout , while redirecting users to different pages in case that same page in inaccessible after logout?

Tags: laravel

I am using `Auth` to login and logout users. The Logout happens if a user clicks on `Logout`, and is redirected to the same page.

Example- If an Authenticated User is in *Contact Us* page; upon clicking `Logout` the user is redirected to Contact Us page, but is Unauthenticated.

***My problem is there are some areas in the site, where the user can access*** **only when** she/he is **logged in** and *logging out while present on this site, should take the user to the **login** page*. I have tried the code below, but that is not helping me solve this problem. In this case, I want the user to be redirected elsewhere.

**Here is the code**

```
public function logoutsuccess(){
  Auth::logout();
  return redirect()->back(); //takes back to the same page after logging out
  Session::flush();
  
  // PreventBackHistory.php middleware and registered in Kernel.php $routeMiddleware to prevent logging in after clicking back button in browser
}
```

Logged in user
[image]

After log out

[image]

Comment: `redirect()->back()` will work for public url and for `auth` urls  once it is logout it will be redirect to login page as middleware have `Authenticate.php`

Comment: I didn't understand. Please elaborate

Comment: That is exactly what is NOT happening, and what I want it to happen

Comment: It says, `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: you want to restrict route access if user not logged in?

Comment: The exact same url where the user was when s/he was logged in

Comment: I will add screenshots here

Comment: @sandy Nope. I want the user to be taken back to the login page after logging out, if s/he was at some place(like edit profile) at the time s/he was logged in

Comment: @KamleshPaul I added some images in the question itself

Comment: did you put `auth` middleware to that route ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes- `Route::post('edit_user', 'userController@edit_details_page')->middleware('auth','PreventBackHistory');`

Comment: put `PreventBackHistory.php` code as well

Comment: @KamleshPaul `<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
`